# I do not succeed in python to print the movie titles from XML file

Tags: python, xml, find, printf

I am trying to get python print all the movie names in the XML file but i can't figure it out. I am pretty new to Python can somebody put me in the right direction?

My code so far:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('text.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for elem in root:
    print(elem.find('movie').get('title'))
```

The XML file:

```
<collection>
    <genre category="Action">
        <decade years="1980s">
            <movie favorite="True" title="Indiana Jones: The raiders of the lost Ark">
                <format multiple="No">DVD</format>
                <year>1981</year>
                <rating>PG</rating>
                <description>
                'Archaeologist and adventurer Indiana Jones
                is hired by the U.S. government to find the Ark of the
                Covenant before the Nazis.'
                </description>
            </movie>
               <movie favorite="True" title="THE KARATE KID">
               <format multiple="Yes">DVD,Online</format>
               <year>1984</year>
               <rating>PG</rating>
               <description>None provided.</description>
            </movie>
            <movie favorite="False" title="Back 2 the Future">
               <format multiple="False">Blu-ray</format>
               <year>1985</year>
               <rating>PG</rating>
               <description>Marty McFly</description>
            </movie>
        </decade>
     </genre>
 </collection>
```

Comment: Hello ! I suggest you try to use the [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) module instead. It's pretty awesome for dealing with XML (and HTML), I think you may have a better time with it in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('text.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for movie in root.iter('movie'):
    print(movie.get('title'))
```

Output:

```
Indiana Jones: The raiders of the lost Ark
THE KARATE KID
Back 2 the Future
```

You can take a look at xml.etree.ElementTree [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BeautifulSoup` as an XML and HTML parser, very quick and straightforward for data extraction.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
xml =open('xml-file').read() 
Soup = bs(xml, 'lxml')
[movie.get('title') for movie in Soup('movie')]
```

Output

```
['Indiana Jones: The raiders of the lost Ark',
 'THE KARATE KID',
 'Back 2 the Future']
```

Comment: Thank you for your awnser i mad this of it but got an error                                `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('text.xml')
xml = tree.getroot()


Soup = bs(xml, 'lxml')
[movie.get('title') for movie in Soup('movie')]`

Comment: Make sure you have `bs4` installed via `pip`. run `pip install bs4` in terminal.

Comment: i have i get: xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: no element found: line 25, column 20

Comment: Ahhh, that is because `BeautifulSoup` parses the XML string, so you have to load it before hand.

Comment: Great, consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small snippet that you might find useful.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('text.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for genre in root:
    for decade in genre:
        for movie in decade:
            print("The movie name is ", movie.attrib['title']) # only get title from the dictionary
```

For more information of xml parser go [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)

Answer (score 0):

The find method only applies to the children of a node.
You forgot the 'decade' level

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('L:\\test (2).xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for elem in root:
    for movies in elem.find('decade'):
        print(movies.get('title'))
```

outputs

```
Indiana Jones: The raiders of the lost Ark
THE KARATE KID
Back 2 the Future
```